# Как в окне проекта "Project" добиться вложенности Animation в AnimatorController?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Возможно, вопрос очень глупый, однако...

Как иерархически вложить `Animation` в `AnimatorController`? Если создать автоматически анимацию для кнопки `Button`, то как раз анимации вложены в контроллер, что удобно для структуры проекта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я сам создаю `AnimationController`, я не могу найти способ создать анимацию сразу внутри, а создаваемые отдельно - создаются как отдельные файлы в структуре проекта...

Как, простите, "*засунуть*" файлы анимации в контроллер? Прошу заметить, что вопрос не про аниматор и машину состояний, а конкретно про структуру папок и файлов проекта...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Руками через редактор это никак не сделать, только через код с помощью [`AssetDatabase.AddObjectToAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.AddObjectToAsset.html).

В принципе тут мало, что можно объяснить - все есть в документации. Однако есть одна проблема с удалением и изменением имен элементов. Если первое решается через `Object.DestroyImmediate` со вторым параметром true, то переименовать такие клипы не получится - придется опять все делать через код. Чтобы не заморачиваться, решил написать простенькое окно с автоматической версткой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно удалять, добавлять и переименовывать вложенные анимации, другого, впрочем, и не надо. Но да, в плане сортировки по имени списки анимаций не совпадают, но это уже мелочи, которые на работоспособность не влияют, да и к вопросу не относятся :)

Код:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Animations;
using UnityEngine;

public static class AnimationControllerEditorExtensions  {
    public class NestedAnimationAdderPopup : EditorWindow {
        private Object animationController;
        private List<Object> nestedAnimations;
        private Object animationToDelete = null; 

        private string newAnimationName = "New animation";

        private Vector2 scrollPosition = Vector2.zero;

        public static void Init() {
            var window = EditorWindow.GetWindow<NestedAnimationAdderPopup>();
            window.name = "Nested animations";

            window.animationController = Selection.objects[0];
            window.nestedAnimations = 
                AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetRepresentationsAtPath(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(Selection.objects[0]))
                .ToList();
        }

        private void OnGUI() {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField(animationController.name);

            scrollPosition = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPosition);
            {
                // добавляем новые анимации
                OnGUI_AddAnimation();

                EditorGUILayout.Space();

                // редактируем и удаляем текущие анимации
                OnGUI_EditExistingAnimations();
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
        }

        private void OnGUI_AddAnimation() {
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            {
                var textFieldRect = EditorGUILayout.GetControlRect();
                var buttonRect = EditorGUILayout.GetControlRect();

                newAnimationName = EditorGUI.TextField(textFieldRect, newAnimationName);
                if (GUI.Button(buttonRect, "Add")) {
                    CreateNestedAnimation(newAnimationName);
                }
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
        private void OnGUI_EditExistingAnimations() {
            foreach (var animation in nestedAnimations) {
                EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                {
                    var textFieldRect = EditorGUILayout.GetControlRect();
                    var buttonRect = EditorGUILayout.GetControlRect();

                    string newName = EditorGUI.TextField(textFieldRect, animation.name);
                    if (animation.name != newName) {
                        animation.name = newName;
                        AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(animationController));
                    }
                    if (GUI.Button(buttonRect, "Delete")) {
                        animationToDelete = animation;
                    }
                }
                EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            }
            DeleteNestedAnimations();
        }

        private void DeleteNestedAnimations() {
            if (animationToDelete != null) {
                DestroyImmediate(animationToDelete, true);
                nestedAnimations.Remove(animationToDelete);
                animationToDelete = null;
                AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(animationController));
            }
        }
        private void CreateNestedAnimation(string name) {
           var clip = new AnimationClip();
           clip.name = name;
           nestedAnimations.Add(clip);
           AssetDatabase.AddObjectToAsset(clip, animationController);
           AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(animationController));
        }
    }

    [MenuItem("Editor/Nested Animation", priority = 402)]
    static void CreateNestedAnimation() {
        NestedAnimationAdderPopup.Init();
    }

    [MenuItem("Editor/Nested Animation", true)]
    static bool ValidateCreateNestedAnimation() {
        return Selection.objects.Length == 1 && Selection.objects[0] is AnimatorController;
    }
}
```